# Nextflow Pipeline: Unexpected Input "{"

Tags: rna-seq, nextflow, errors

I'm attempting to run a nextflow pipeline and have begun getting unexpected output for a few of the processes in my pipeline. I believe this to be a syntax error, but I am not sure where to correct it. Any help is finding where my error is located is appreciated.

[image: Error]

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
 nextflow.enable.dsl=2
 import groovy.io.*




  process hisat2Alignment {
    fastq1 = NS.1389.002.NEBNext_dual_i7_*_R1.fastq.gz
    fastq2 = NS.1389.002.NEBNext_dual_i7_*_R2.fastq.gz
    input:
    tuple path("fastq1"), path("fastq2")

    output:
    tuple path("*.sam"), val(fastq1.baseName.substring(0, fastq1.baseName.indexOf("_R1")))
    script:
    """
    hisat2 -p 16 -x genome -1 ${fastq1} -2 ${fastq2} -S mapped_${baseName}.sam
    """


 }

process Stringtier {
    publishDir "${params.baseDir}/assembled/$baseName", mode: "move"
    env {
     PATH = $PATH:/data/selena/stringtie-2.2.1
    }

    input:
    tuple path(mapped_bam), val(baseName)
    output:
    tuple path("*.gtf"), val(baseName)


    script:
    """
    stringtie -e -G ${params.annotation} -o ${baseName}.gtf ${mapped_bam}

    """
}

 workflow {
    samples = new File(params.configFilePath).readLines()*.split('\t');
    samples  = Channel.fromList(samples);
    hisat2Alignment(samples);
    assembled = Stringtier(samples)
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nextflow does not have an `env` process directive. If `stringtie` is not already in your `$PATH`, you'll need to append it before running `nextflow`, for example:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/data/selena/stringtie-2.2.1"
nextflow run de-pipeline.nf
```

However, you may prefer to avoid local tool installations altogether, and use either the [`conda`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#conda) or [`container`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#container) process directives. The latter will however require a container runtime, like [Docker](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/container.html#docker) or [Singularity](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/container.html#singularity).

You may also consider including a 'sample name' or some sort of sample identifier in your config file, which I suspect is just a simple tab-separated file of filenames. This would greatly simplify your workflow. For example:

```
params.samplesheet = './samples.tsv'
params.genome = './genomes/GRCh38/GRCh38'
params.gtf = './Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.gtf'

genome_name = file( params.genome ).name
genome_path = file( params.genome ).parent

params.outdir = './results'
```

```
process HISAT2 {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/HISAT2/${sample}", mode: 'copy'

    cpus 16

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(reads)
    path genome_dir

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}.sam")

    script:
    def (r1, r2) = reads

    """
    hisat2 \\
        -p ${task.cpus} \\
        -x "${genome_dir}/${genome_name}" \\
        -1 "${r1}" \\
        -2 "${r2}" \\
        -S "${sample}.sam"
    """
}
```

```
process SAMtools_sort {

    tag { sample }

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(bam)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}.sorted.bam")

    """
    samtools sort \\
        -o "${sample}.sorted.bam" \\
        "${bam}"
    """
}
```

```
process StringTie {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/StringTie/${sample}", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(bam)
    path gtf

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}.gtf")

    """
    stringtie \\
        -e \\
        -G "${gtf}" \\
        -o "${sample}.gtf" \\
        "${bam}"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    gtf = file( params.gtf )

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.samplesheet )
        .splitCsv( sep: '\t' )
        .map { sample, fq1, fq2 ->
            def reads = tuple( file(fq1), file(fq2) )

            tuple( sample, reads )
        }
        .set { samples }

    HISAT2( samples, genome_path )

    SAMtools_sort( HISAT2.out )

    StringTie( SAMtools_sort.out, gtf )
}
```

Where the contents of the input sample sheet (e.g. `samples.tsv`) looks like:

```
sample_A    /path/to/reads/A_R1.fastq.gz    /path/to/reads/A_R2.fastq.gz
sample_B    /path/to/reads/B_R1.fastq.gz    /path/to/reads/B_R2.fastq.gz
sample_C    /path/to/reads/C_R1.fastq.gz    /path/to/reads/C_R2.fastq.gz
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [adoring_poisson] DSL2 - revision: 43e8c59949
executor >  local (9)
[60/1cba2f] process > HISAT2 (sample_A)        [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[0a/931a07] process > SAMtools_sort (sample_A) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[6d/7689a2] process > StringTie (sample_A)     [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
```